# Time measurement - many measurements and variable in an iterval

Tags: python, function, time, measurement

I am to measure how long does it take for my function to represent C:

```
C in range (0, 100, 1)
```

with integers from a list which is given.
There is my code:

```
import itertools
import time    
def amount(c):
    a = [1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50]

    dp = [[0 for _ in range(len(a))] for __ in range(c + 1)]
    dp[0][0] = 1

    for i in range(c):
        for j in range(len(a)):
            for k in range(j, len(a)):
                if i + a[k] <= c:
                     dp[i + a[k]][k] += dp[i][j]

    return sum(dp[c])
```

I decided to create a function which measures how long does one call of my function last:

```
def count_once(c):
    start = time.perf_counter()
    amount(c)
    return time.perf_counter() - start
```

It's pretty easy. Now I would like to make 10 measurements for each C from 0 to 100 and then to count the average from those measurements for each C.
So the output should contain 100 numbers (each number would be the average).
I started with this:

```
for i in range(0, 101, 1):
    count_once(i)
    print(count_once(i))
```

But I have no idea how can I use that formula to calculate an average of 10 measurements for each C.

Comment: sum([count_once(I) for I in range(100)])/100.0?

Comment: @kabanus but I need 100 different averages. I would like to measure time 10 times for each C and then count an average for each C.

Comment: So you mean you mean you want to average count_once over 10 times for 10 different arguments? Say C=0...9?

Comment: @kabanus I would like to use count_once 10 times for C = 1. And count the average. Then use count_once 10 times for C = 2. And again - average. And so on till C = 100. At the end I would like to have 100 averages for each C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not:

```
for C in range(100):
     print "C=",C,"averages",sum([count_once(C) for_ in range(10)])/10.0
```

You can easily change the first `range(100)` with any list/iterable of `C` values you want to test, and the 10s on the second line with the amount you want to average over.

By the way to eliminate the timing overhead I would go about this a bit differently:

```
def count(c,times):
    start = time.perf_counter()
    for _ in range(times): amount(c)
    return (time.perf_counter() - start)/float(times)
```

Then your outer loop becomes:

```
for C in range(100): print "C=",C,"averages",count(C,10)
```

I would probably use more times than 10 (say 100 or 1000 at least).

Comment: I want to note here that range(0,101,1)=range(101) and yields numbers from 0 to 100 (101 numbers).

Comment: Thanks a lot! That really helps me and what is nice - the solution isn't very complex. Yes, of course - you're right. I made a mistake with ranges. Is the elimination of the timing overhead really important?

Comment: Usually is. Try and test it! Run the count function with times=1,10,100,1000 and see if there are differences! Also don't forget to mark accepted - that's the V next to the up/downvote - so users know this has been answered.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to test it :) I'm new to Python so I need some time to learn what is and what isn't important!